# SynchronizationLockException when using Threading::Monitor on String

Tags: multithreading, winforms, visual-c++, locking

I think we are having an issue on using Monitor::TryEnter and Monitor::Exit on a String (I suppose this is the issue, but I'm looking for some extra information).

```
    if (Monitor::TryEnter(m_sLogFile, 200)) {
        try {
            m_sLogFile = IO::Path::GetDirectoryName(Application::ExecutablePath) + "\\" + LOG_FILE_DEFAULT;
            // SOME EXTRA CODE
        }
        finally {
            Monitor::Exit(m_sLogFile);
        }
    }
```

[m_sLogFile is a String declared in my class]

The **SynchronizationLockException** is thrown on Monitor::Exit call, with this message:

> Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block
>   of code

I want to be sure that error is that we are locking the string and we are changing its content.

Comment: Don't synchronize on strings. Don't synchronize on non read-only fields.

Comment: Ok, can you also give some extra documentation about this? In order to completely understand it. :)

Comment: Well you're not changing the content if your string (considering that that's impossible to do in c#) you're replacing the insurance with another and then trying to unlock the never locked instance. You should really just ask a question about what you're trying to do - these guidelines exist exactly to avoid people doing complex things that are likely to go wrong, better ask experts if you think you need to violate these constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that you are using a `string` for `Monitor.Enter/Exit`, the problem is that you are using **one** string for `Enter` and **different one** for `Exit`:

```
if (Monitor::TryEnter(m_sLogFile, 200)) {
    try {
        m_sLogFile = IO::Path::GetDirectoryName(Application::ExecutablePath) + "\\" + LOG_FILE_DEFAULT;
            // SOME EXTRA CODE
    }
    finally {
        Monitor::Exit(m_sLogFile);
    }
}
```

See the `m_sLogFile = ....` inside?

You need to use a field which doesn't change (something like `readonly object m_Lock;` should be sufficient).

Comment: Ok, this confirm my idea and the solution you provide is the same we decided to use. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest only one fix: I noticed that you write "readonly object m_Lock;", readonly is used in C#, perhaps you meant initonly? I think this should be the same.

Comment: @LucaMus Oops, I've totally missed the C++ tag. But yes, `initonly` or whatever is the C++ equivalent of C# `readonly`.